# PyQt5: Adding of virtual column for standard item model fails

Tags: view, model, pyqt5, qstandarditemmodel, virtual-column

I have a QStandardItemModel where each item manages a database entity, so every row has one column and the rows adjust matching to the database events.
Now I want to generate a table from one subtree of this model, not a list. Therefore, every item will be asked for two different values and a proxy model will display them as two cells of a row. **I don't want to change the standard item model.** I want to have a proxy model that displays to values per item in separate columns. The standard item model has only one column.

When I created the model the first column got displayed as expected, but the second one was neither selectable nor enabled and all cells of the column were empty.
Below you'll find my MWE for reproduction.

I tried generating different indices for the columns but **The data() method only gets called for indices with column=0**, so the problem is not about roles where I shouldn't return None or other stuff.
**Even flags() are ignored for the second column.**

I expected a two columned table with my data displayed based on the items my model holds.

In my MWE I don't use the item's original text, but return a dummy text for all items that definetly can be calculated and is identifying.

What I get is this table with a phantom like second column:

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0-0 |  |
| 1-0 |  |
| 2-0 |  |

Why is this happening and how can I add my column with extra data?

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSortFilterProxyModel, QModelIndex, Qt, QIdentityProxyModel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel


VARIANT = 2  # 1 or 2


class AddProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def columnCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        return 2

    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, role: int = ...):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(section)
        return super(AddProxyModel, self).headerData(section, orientation, role)

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = ...):
        if index.column() != 0:
            print("Called for something != 0")
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return f"{index.row()}-{index.column()}"

        new_index = self.index(index.row(), 0, index.parent())

        return super(AddProxyModel, self).data(
            index if VARIANT == 1 else new_index,
            role
        )

    def flags(self, index: QModelIndex) -> Qt.ItemFlags:
        return Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = QStandardItemModel()

    model.appendRow(QStandardItem("A"))
    model.appendRow(QStandardItem("B"))
    model.appendRow(QStandardItem("C"))

    # p = QIdentityProxyModel()
    # p.setSourceModel(model)

    proxy = AddProxyModel()
    # proxy.setSourceModel(p)  # also not working
    proxy.setSourceModel(model)

    table = QTableView()
    table.setModel(proxy)
    table.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Creating "virtual columns" (or rows, for what's worth) is not easy, and requires to implement more complex aspects of the models (starting with `index()`). In reality, most of the times it's not worth the complexity, and creating a *related* model that properly connects to the source model signals (row/column insert/removal/movement, data changes, etc) is actually simpler. This is similar to what QConcatenateTablesProxyModel does, and, interestingly enough, it does *not* inherit from QAbstractProxyModel.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help. I'll now implement this version. I've already experienced in other situations that Qt (Proxy-)Models often cause errors that are difficult to track.

Comment: Errors that are difficult to track are often just a symptom. There are normally three types of proxy models: identity (altering data), sorting (altering layout) and filtering (limiting contents). All of them can only alter the data or the shape, with the latter case in a subtractive form: you can normally show *less* rows/columns, not more, and that's because their mechanism allows to *filter* existing indexes, but doesn't allow to create new ones. In order to show more rows or columns the model has to be able to create new QModelIndexes, but that would affect other functions that rely on it.

Comment: Note that QAbstractProxyModel subclasses are fundamentally QAbstractItemModels based classes that keep mapping of existing indexes of a source model. Qt devs created that class to provide an easy method to get such a mapping (mostly for sort/filter purposes), but they fundamentally are just separate models that return the source data, eventually altering (or limiting) the existing shape. If you got errors from such models, it's probably because they were used in the wrong way (usually, trying to access wrong indexes). If you can read c++, I suggest you to study their code.

Comment: Thank you very much, once I also got strange errors when I only tried to filter data from a model with sorting. But that's not so important because I solved it without a proxy.